# Postgres query to combine multiple rows with same value of a column into a single row

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, group-by

I have this table:

[image]

and would like to convert it to the following:

[image]

Please help me, been stuck on it for way too long. Doesn't working for me using group by

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] for tips how to write a useful question and include a [example] showing what you have already tried.

Comment: Your question is really very low on details. Please DDL and describe better what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH A as (SELECT id, a FROM XXX WHERE a is not null),
     B as (SELECT id, b FROM XXX WHERE b is not null)
SELECT A.a, B.b, A.id FROM A 
     INNER JOIN B on A.id = B.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this dataset, simple aggregation would do what you want:

```
select min(a) a, min(b) b, id
from mytable
group by id
```

This takes advantage of the fact that aggregate functions ignore `null` values; we could get the very same result with `max()` as we did with `min()`.

Comment: I'm actually sending out these column values as array in a function. So it's getting iterated row by row. Is there any way we can get the desired output through a query if we pass each row once at a time? Can't use aggregate functions.

Comment: Yes, you can use ON CONFLICT statement to update row when duplicate ID, but you will need some constraint on ID to do it.